# Save contents of

Tags: php, html, email, pdf

i have a file which generates html and adds it to a php String using buffer

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>

    <table>
     <tr>
      <td>Content</td>
     </tr>
    </table>

<?php     
    $contents = ob_get_contents();
    ob_flush();

    mail($to, $subject, $contents, $headers);
?>
```

Is there a way to save the contents of the string as a pdf file on the server using php?
I have tried using FPDF but it does not work since the content is at the top of the page and i get a output error from fpdf.

Any help appreciated

Comment: FPDF is the right way... but its not as easy as it seems look up tutorials for fpdf

Comment: I have tried a few. it seems it only works when fpdf runs alone on the page without any other functions or html.

Comment: you have to make shure that there is no output before the pdf header , so nur echos or whitespace before you print out the pdf

Comment: Yeah, but unfortunately the contents in the buffer cause output before the pdf header. and it needs to be before else the fpdf can't include the contents because it comes first. However if there is a way to include a string which is created only later(after) the fpdf code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `ob_end_clean()` instead of `ob_flush();`

`ob_flush();` will print the html and you don't want that. As FPDF creates a pdf and needs to manipulate the headers (to be a pdf). If you echo/print something first php will automatically set default header. The library can't modify them once they are set resulting in error.

after you have put the content of the ob in a var (`$contents = ob_get_contents();`) you can use `ob_end_clean()`. This will discard the content of the buffer and stop buffering.